# How to display 5 lines immediately before a line in a config file using tail and head

Tags: linux

So I want to display 5 lines immediately before a line that says `# Step #6: Configure output plugins` in the snort.conf file.

so I use the following to get the line number:

```
nl /etc/snort/snort.conf | grep output
```

and the line number is 445

the book then advises to use the following:

```
tail -n+445 /etc/snort/snort.conf | head -n 6
```

but this doesn't work and does not display the 5 line before line 445

Comment: What's wrong with `grep -B 5 output /etc/snort/snort.conf`?

Comment: I need to know why the above method is not working...it will help me better understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tail -n +445` outputs lines starting from 445. `head -n 6` shows the first 6 lines of output.

Together, they show lines 445-451.

If you instead want to show 439-445, you have to adjust accordingly:

```
tail -n +439 /etc/snort/snort.conf  | head -n 6
```

Comment: thanks but I tried your method but it's not showing the lines but instead the following: enable_respoverflow enable_sshlcrc32 \ enable_srvoverflow enable_protomishmatch

Comment: In that case you have the wrong line number. Note that `nl` does not count blank lines while `head` and `tail` does. You can use `nl -b a` to make `nl` count all lines

Comment: Good point. You can also simply use `grep -n pattern files...` to get the line numbers of the matches. But if that is the problem, OP's numbers will be early. I.e. if the match is line 10 with 2 blank lines prior, the starting line will be 8 which is in the range of the file.

Comment: THANK YOU! Finally, solved. I been pulling my hair out. I guess I should have studied 'man nl' but I've literally only started using the linux terminal a week ago. I just hope all of this makes sense eventually. Thank you again. Life saver.

Comment: Can someone explain why `nl -b a snorky.config` to get the starting line number would fix that particular error? Actually I can not even generate that error by entering a starting line that is beyond the end of the config file????? And as per my other comment, the blank lines would result in a starting line that is too early in the file and never beyond the end of the file.

Comment: @GMc There is no error message, only wrong output. MCVE: `printf '\ngoat\nsports car\n' | nl` will output `2 sports car`. However, when you fetch line #2: `printf '\ngoat\nsports car\n' | tail -n +2 | head -n 1` you instead get `goat`

Comment: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted the messsages (e.g. overflow etc) as errors as opposed to configuration settings).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `grep` command to look back few lines before the match:

```
 grep -B 5 output /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Will print 5 lines before each line that match "output"

From [`grep` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

> -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>
> Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines. Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of
>   matches. With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and
>   a warning is given.

Comment: while it technically doesn't answer OP's question, this is probably the easiest and least error prone answer, especially since `grep` is already being used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using `tail -n+445 snort.conf` means start from line 445 and output to the end of the file. `head -n 5` means get the first 5 lines from that. So you start at 445 then take the first 5 lines. Thus you get lines 445, 446, 447, 448 and 449.

You need your tail value to be 445 - 5 = 440. So try

`tail -n+440 snort.conf | head -n 5`

Oh yeah, and I would definitely use grep -B for this. You should also check out -A (lines after the match) and -C (lines before as well as lines after the match)!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my linux set up in virtual box because I'm not getting the lines displayed but instead something beginning with 'enable_respoverflow enable_sshlcrc32 \ enable_srvoverflow enable_protomishmatch'

Comment: Does your original command that displays the following 5/6 lines still work? Also, make sure you manually type the command (not copy and paste). It is unlikely but it is possible that something might be autocorrecting some characters for you.

Comment: Solved now, I think you commented above but thanks for your help. 'nl -b a' fixed it.